# Components are not receiving route props

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The docs state

> All three render methods will be passed the same three route props
> match location history

And they showcase it with this example

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

// All route props (match, location and history) are available to User
function User(props) {
  return <h1>Hello {props.match.params.username}!</h1>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Route path="/user/:username" component={User} />
  </Router>,
  node
);
```

Seems easy enough.

But then I try it with my code and that's not working.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isFalsy, readFromStorage } from 'utils/general.utils';

import { Homepage } from './pages/homepage/Loadable';
import { Header } from './global/components';
import { Register } from './pages/auth/register/Loadable';
import { Login } from './pages/auth/login/Loadable';
import { ACCESS_TOKEN } from 'constants/storage.constants';

const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const accessToken = readFromStorage(ACCESS_TOKEN);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        !isFalsy(accessToken) ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export function App(props) {
  const routes = [
    {
      path: ['/'],
      component: Homepage,
      exact: true,
      private: false,
    },
    {
      path: ['/register'],
      component: Register,
      private: false,
    },
    {
      path: ['/login'],
      component: Login,
      private: false,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        {routes.map(route => {
          const Component = route.component;
          const RouteWrapper = route.private ? PrivateRoute : Route;
          return (
            <RouteWrapper
              key={route.path[0]}
              path={route.path}
              exact={route.exact}
            >
              <Component {...props} />
            </RouteWrapper>
          );
        })}
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

And yes I am wrapping my `App` in `ReactDom` likeso

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <HelmetProvider>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </HelmetProvider>
  </Provider>,
  ROOT,
);
```

But the `Register`, `Login` and `Home` component don't have the props of the route. What am I doing wrong here?

I am using v5.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You simply are not passing the route props on through to the rendered components since you are always rendering children components as wrapped children and *not* on one of `render`, `component`, or `children` props.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const accessToken = readFromStorage(ACCESS_TOKEN);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        !isFalsy(accessToken) ? (
          children // <-- Just renders children, passes no props
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

And you pass along the props that were passed to App

```
export function App(props) { // <-- props
  const routes = [....];

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        {routes.map(route => {
          const Component = route.component;
          const RouteWrapper = route.private ? PrivateRoute : Route;
          return (
            <RouteWrapper
              key={route.path[0]}
              path={route.path}
              exact={route.exact}
            >
              <Component {...props} /> // <-- spread here, no route props
            </RouteWrapper>
          );
        })}
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

## Solution

1. Rewrite your `PrivateRoute` component to render either a `Route` or `Redirect` so the route props can be passed along.

   ```
   const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
     const accessToken = readFromStorage(ACCESS_TOKEN);

     return !isFalsy(accessToken) ? (
       <Route {...props} />
     ) : (
       <Redirect
         to={{
           pathname: '/login',
           state: { from: props.location },
         }}
       />
     );
   };
   ```
2. Pass (*nearly*) the entire route config object to the wrapper. Here you will be spreading `path`, `exact`, `component` (or `render`, etc) into either a `Route` or `PrivateRoute` which will pass on the route props.

   ```
   <Switch>
     {routes.map(({ private: isPrivate, ...props }) => {
       const RouteWrapper = isPrivate ? PrivateRoute : Route;
       return (
         <RouteWrapper
           key={props.path[0]}
           {...props}
         />
       );
     })}
   </Switch>
   ```

## Demo

[image: Edit components-are-not-receiving-route-props]

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I do see what you mean now. Thanks for having a look with me Drew, appreciate it!
The only thing  I still need to do now I have the `history`, is pass it to my `redux-saga` so I can navigate in my sagas!! :)